# Sitecore 9 Commerce set up in a distributed environment

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-commerce-server

I am trying to install Sitecore Commerce on Sitecore 9 Update 1 on a distributed environment. It would be great if i could get clarification on two questions.

1. The xConnect services and Solr runs on different VM's. If I run the powershell script after commenting out the SOLR and xConnect code, how can I manually set it up in these VM's. Is there any guidance available on this.
2. I would also like to split out Authoring, Minions, Shops, Ops, BizFx and Identity Server onto different VMs as part of a POC on scaling up. But the powershell script for installing Commerce does not do a Role based installation. How can I achieve this with the existing script.